# How to set wireframe line width in Blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

I must have accidentally changed a setting that causes wireframe lines to be unrecognizably thin.

When I load factory settings, everything is back to normal. However, I would like to keep my own settings apart from the line widths. Does anyone know what I need to change?

The "interface > display > line width" setting is set to Auto in both cases.

I am attaching two screenshots to explain the difference.

[image: My settings with thin lines]
[image: Factory settings with normal lines]